# Average margin bounds for separable SVM

Tags: machine-learning, lg.learning, st.statistics, svm

Suppose we're training a linear separator in the realizable PAC setting. Given $m$ labeled examples $(x_i,y_i)$ in $\mathbb R^d\times\{-1,1\}$, a (consistent) *linear separator* is a vector $w\in\mathbb R^d$ with $||w||=1$, such that
$$ y_i(w\cdot x_i)=:\gamma_i>0
$$
for all $1\le i\le m$. Putting $R_i=||x_i||$, we can define the *margin* of the $i$th example as $R_i/\gamma_i$ and the sample margin as
$$ \min_{1\le i\le m} R_i/\gamma_i.$$
This quantity is known to control the generalization error, see e.g. here 
https://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~karyeh/opt-svm.pdf
for the precise statements.

Question: are there any generalization bounds for the above setting in terms of the *average* margin, $\frac1m\sum_{i=1}^m R_i/\gamma_i$ --- as opposed to the worst-case one, as above?

Comment: https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=656008

Comment: Nice! But you don't actually use the quantity $\frac1m\sum_{i=1}^m R_i/\gamma_i$, right?

Comment: No. That why it was not an answer. Just a remotely relevant result.