# Average smoothness learning rates

Tags: machine-learning, lg.learning, st.statistics

This question is somewhat related to [this one](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/41724/average-margin-bounds-for-separable-svm). There are many results in statistics where convergence rates (including minimax ones) are given in terms of the *smoothness* properties of the underlying function class: Lipschitz, Hölder, etc. The problem with these is that they're quite pessimistic: a function with a high oscillation on a tiny region of the space is penalized the same as a function with high oscillation everywhere. Are there generalization bounds that take into account average-case smoothness? The one classic example is functions of bounded variation at most $V$ on $[0,1]$, whose $\gamma$-shattering dimension is $1+\lfloor\frac{V}{2\gamma}\rfloor$ (see the [Anthony-Bartlett](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~bartlett/nnl/index.html) book). For differentiable $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$, the bounded variation is given by $\int_0^1|f'(x)|dx$, and thus corresponds to an average measure of smoothness.

Can anyone point me to other results along these lines for more general spaces?